# Is it good ideo seo point of view- to give noindex or nofollow to labels and tags?

Tags: seo, blog, nofollow, noindex, tags

Is it a good idea seo point of view to give `noindex` or `nofollow`  to labels and tags?

I am creating a blog with tagging post. What is the best strategy for tag pages?